# How to add events to dynamically created controls (buttons, listboxes) in Excel VBA userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a userform in real time.  (in Excel VBA)  Just to try-out, I started with 2 labels, a textbox, a combobox and a commandbutton.  I list the code below + the resulting form.

My question is:  How can I get events linked to the controls, specifically the combobox and commandbutton?  Normally (with manually created forms), this would be done by the routines called: cmbTabel_change() and cmdExit_click().  But this doesn't seem to work, when they are dynamically created.  Who can help me?

Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim cCont As Control

    Call Add_Control(cCont, "Label", "lblDatabase", "Database", 30, 23, 60, 18)
    Call Add_Control(cCont, "Textbox", "txtDatabase", "Database", 110, 20, 60, 18)
    Call Add_Control(cCont, "Label", "lblTabel", "Tabel", 30, 47, 90, 18)
    Call Add_Control(cCont, "Combobox", "cmbTabel", "Tabel", 110, 44, 90, 18)
    Call Add_Control(cCont, "CommandButton", "cmdExit", "Afsluiten", 210, 140, 54, 18)
End Sub

Private Sub Add_Control(ctrl, ctp, cnm, cap, l, t, w, h)
    Set ctrl = Me.controls.Add("Forms." & ctp & ".1", cnm)
    With ctrl
        .Left = l
        .Top = t
        .Width = w
        .Height = h
    End With

    Select Case ctp
    Case "Combobox"
        controls(cnm).Clear
        For j = 1 To 5
            controls(cnm).AddItem "ListItem" & j
        Next j
        controls(cnm).ListIndex = 0
    Case "Label", "CommandButton"
        With controls(cnm)
            .Caption = cap
        End With
    Case "Textbox"
        controls(cnm).Text = cap
    End Select
End Sub
```

Resulting form:

[image]

Comment: In order to add code to a VBA project you need access to the VBA project which to grant is not recommended while you are connected to the Internet. Anyone could take control of your computer. Therefore the better way would be to write the code before you create the form that uses it.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to build a class to handle the events on the controls.

As an example create a new class module called `clsMyEvents`.
Add this code to the class:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyCombo As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents MyButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub MyCombo_Change()
    MsgBox MyCombo.Name & " was changed to value " & MyCombo.Value
End Sub

Private Sub MyButton_Click()

    Dim BtnNum As Long

    BtnNum = Replace(MyButton.Name, "MyButton", "")

    MsgBox MyButton.Name & " is " & IIf(BtnNum Mod 2 = 0, "even", "odd")

End Sub
```

Note:  When you enter the `WithEvents` you'll be able to select *most* events associated with that type of control.

Next, create a blank `UserForm` and add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public MyEvents As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim tmpCtrl As Control
    Dim CmbEvent As clsMyEvents
    Dim x As Long

    'Add some dummy data for the combo-boxes.
    Sheet1.Range("A1:A5") = Application.Transpose(Array("Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Pink"))
    Sheet1.Range("B1:B5") = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
    Sheet1.Range("C1:C5") = Application.Transpose(Array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1))

    For x = 1 To 5
        'Add the control.
        Set tmpCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "MyCombobox" & x)
        With tmpCtrl
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 80
            .Top = (x * 20) - 18 'You might have to adjust this spacing.  I just made it up.
            .RowSource = "Sheet1!" & Sheet1.Cells(1, x).Resize(5).Address
        End With

        'Attach the event.
        Set CmbEvent = New clsMyEvents
        Set CmbEvent.MyCombo = tmpCtrl
        MyEvents.Add CmbEvent

    Next x

    For x = 1 To 5
        Set tmpCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "MyButton" & x)
        With tmpCtrl
            .Left = 100
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 20
            .Top = (x * 20) - 18
            .Caption = "Num " & x
        End With

        Set CmbEvent = New clsMyEvents
        Set CmbEvent.MyButton = tmpCtrl
        MyEvents.Add CmbEvent
    Next x

End Sub
```

**Edit:** I've updated to include code for a command button as well.
When you change the value in a combobox it will tell you the name of the control and the value it was changed to.  When you click a button it will tell you if the number on it is odd or even.