# VBA - How to insert characters from the press of a command button

Tags: vba

I'm building a home surveillance system for use in my home and possibly to publish on my blog. However; I've ran into a problem. We only use a mouse for input, and most people use only mouse. So, I needed to build an on-screen keyboard. I got a VBA frame and put a text box, and layed out a load of buttons to make a keyboard. I need help with the code that makes it so that when you press a key it will put that character in the text input box so that the user can see what they are entering. If you know, or could suggest a fix, please reply! Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use the built-in windows on-screen keyboard?

Comment: Because that would be a pain to trigger, especially if running on a mac, I'd rather implement my own one that blends nicely, and I can add extra buttons for certain features

Comment: `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(): Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value & "A": End Sub`

Comment: Works perfectly, great formatting by the way! Thank you very much!

Comment: I would suggest to create the buttons on the form dynamically within loop, and to create a class that will handle events from buttons clicks.

Comment: One question, how do I do the other controls like backspace (How do I remove characters from the textbox)

Comment: How would I do that please? Code?

Comment: For backspace use `If Not Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then Me.TextBox1.Value = Left(Me.TextBox1.Value, Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) - 1)`

Comment: Perfect! Only one more problem. How can I scroll through the textbox? I have a scrollbar (The two arrow buttons), could I use these to scrool the cursor through the input or do I program two seperate buttons?

Comment: Take a look e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48384652/2165759) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3014421/2165759) for creating controls dynamically and adding event handling.

Comment: Sorry but I'm scratching my head as VBA gives me errors whilst trying to configure this code. Could you give me some code I don't mind if it's for scroll bar buttons or two seperate buttons

Comment: Either set `TextBox` property `ScrollBars` to `1 - fmScrollBarsHorizontal`, or set property `TextAlign` to `3 - fmTextAlignRight` and add the line `Me.TextBox1.SetFocus` in each button click event handler.

Comment: Ok cheers. How do I get the text from the keyboard put into the username and password boxes? Would I have to add the box to the list on the buttons

Comment: For example: Me.currentkey.Value = Me.currentkey.Value , ADD HERE & "m"

Comment: To type text into multiply textboxes you need to 1) dim a private variable in userform module scope, 2) refer to it within each button click event handler (instead of hard coded `Me.TextBox1`), 3) and reference the variable to the textbox within each textbox enter event handler, and 3a) on userform initialization event.

Comment: I'm still confused... Could you give me some example code for the private variable?

Comment: `Private oCurrentTextBox As MSForms.TextBox` at the top of the userform module.