# Add code to dynamically added checkbox in form VBA

Tags: vba

I wrote sub which add checkbox like below

```
Sub WstawCHB(i As Integer, ByVal ws As Worksheet)
Dim NewCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Set NewCheckBox = ListaObecnosciForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "CB" & i, True)
With NewCheckBox
    .Top = 20 * i
    .Left = 20
    .Width = 450
    .Height = 24
    .Caption = ws.Cells(2 + i, 27)
    .Value = False
End With

End Sub
```

How to add some action to the checkbox in code. For example (.OnAction = "CheckBox1_Click")

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Additional information: the Sub is calling in loop in code below, so I have to "inject" code for every created checkbox for each iteration of loop

```
Sub DodajCHB(ByVal LW As Integer, ByVal ws As Worksheet)

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While i < LW
    Call WstawCHB(i, ws)
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: [How to add events to dynamically created controls (buttons, listboxes) in Excel VBA userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382957/how-to-add-events-to-dynamically-created-controls-buttons-listboxes-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks Darren. Now I have a problem with setting some peperty in the class "clsMyEvents" which allow these variables to be read from and written to (Property Get Property Let functions or Property Set for object type variables). Is it possible to do this with this type of class?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  `Public Property Get SomeProperty() As String: SomeProperty = pSomeProperty: End Property` and `Public Property Let SomeProperty(Value As String): pSomeProperty = Value: End Property`.  This might help:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add events to dynamically created controls (buttons, listboxes) in Excel VBA userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382957/how-to-add-events-to-dynamically-created-controls-buttons-listboxes-in-excel)